# Clusterered and non-clustered index vs primary and secondary index

Tags: sql, database, indices

I am quite confused by the differences between clustered and non-clustered indices vs primary and secondary indices. Are clustered indices and primary indices the same thing? Likewise, is secondary indices and non-clustered indices the same. Or is there a difference? And if so what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, by "primary index" you mean the index on the primary key.

If so, a "primary index" differs from secondary indexes primary because the primary index is always unique.  Secondary indexes might or might not be unique.

Some databases (but not all) support *clustered indexes*.  There can be at most one clustered index per table, because it is the index used for ordering the rows on the data pages.  Some databases that support clustered indexes require that the clustering index be the primary key index (i.e. they are the same).  Some databases make the primary key clustered by default, but you can override it.

So, primary indexes, secondary indexes, and clustered indexes are three different things, but they can overlap.